# How to assign two objects to one object by just attributes

Tags: javascript, assign

In Adonisjs,

```
companys = await DB....(fetch from database)
userinfo = {
        companys: companys,
    }
let finalUser = {
    ...auth.user,
    ...userinfo
}
```

result is

```
{
  __setters__: [
    '$attributes',
    '$persisted',
    ,,,
    '$visible',
    '$hidden'
  ],
  '$attributes': {
    id: 'd25...',
    display_name: 'AAA',
    username: 'BBB',
    email: 'CCC',
    password: 'DDD',
  ...
  'company' : { ... }
```

What I have to do is,

```
id: 'd25...',
display_name: 'AAA',
username: 'BBB',
email: 'CCC',
password: 'DDD',
...
company : { ... }
```

How can I make merge two object?

```
{
    'user' : auth.user,
    'userinfo' : userinfo
}
```

works fine. But I want that 'userinfo' be one of the property of the original user object. Something like this.

```
{
    auth.user,
    'userinfo' : userinfo
}
```

Comment: What are you getting for auth.user?

Comment: `{
    ...auth.user.$attributes,
    'userinfo' : userinfo
}`